# Is my Galaxy s7 edge hacked?

Tags: google, music

My phone's volume gets messed up. It turns all the way up and down even without headphones. My google assistant keeps popping up, my music gets skipped or interrupted by google assistant, and the google sound is almost constantly going off. Even when my phone is off this happens. My ringer goes up and down and vibrates all the time. It can be a little awkward in public. I've suspected for a few months that it has been hacked because it will also heat up so bad it will actually burn me. I used to get adds on my phone but they're gone. Although, a while ago I thought the adds were gone after a few weeks they did come back, but they are gone now.

I'm also only fourteen years old and have taken baths with my phone to listen to music which is scary. It's getting worse everyday and I'm not sure what to do. If you could help that would be great, thanks.

Comment: It sounds more like you've got water into your volume buttons than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it is not a hack. Hackers typically hack to gain benefit somehow, and they don't benefit from adjusting the volume on your phone.

That being said, a lot of your problems seem to stem from your hardware buttons. It is possible that your buttons may have excess dirt or dust inside the housing or became sensitive due to overuse, mashing, or just plain wear and tear. Those could be some possible causes of your volume issues and random Google Assistant activation. It would also explain the vibration as turning your ringer volume all the way down causes your phone to go to vibrate mode.

And for your phone heating up, it is common for phones to heat up while charging, if the screen is on for a long time, if the phone has been left in direct sunlight, or if the phone battery health is deteriorating.

If you are still very concerned about yourself being hacked, you can back up your files to a computer or cloud and factory reset your phone. If the issues persist, then it is just due to hardware issues and not hacking.